# Version Mismatch Error with Onion-Py Library

Tags: onion-routing, python

### I've been hunting around trying to figure out why Onion-Py is throwing this error. I had a fresh install and running python 2.7

### onion_py.manager.MajorVersionMismatchError: Received OnionOO document with version 3, this library only supports up to version 2.

Anyone else encounter this?

[image]

Comment: Which version of the OnionPy package are you running? (And are you _certain_ you're on Python version 2.7?)

Comment: v 0.3.2. and I am 100% positive I'm on 2.7 (2.7.3 to be exact).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to figure out a way to ensure you are running Python 2.7 and try again.

Most likely you aren't using python 2.7 like you think you are.

Check python from command line by typing `python --version`.

Then to make sure login to Python command line by typing `python` and see what version it spits out in the welcome message and type `exit()` to exit.

Once you confirm you are running 2.7x then install onionpy via pip: `pip install onionpy`. Also make sure you have Tor running, or onionpy will malfunction.

Do a test (should return summary of current relays)

```
from onion_py.manager import Manager
from onion_py.caching import OnionSimpleCache
manager = Manager(OnionSimpleCache())
s = manager.query('summary', limit=4)
print s.relays[0].fingerprint
print s.relays[0].nickname
exit()
```

Comment: I'm running 2.7.3, I've never install anything other than 2.7 on this machine. I'll edit the OP with a screengrab

Comment: @T.J. Hmm strange. I'm looking into it. What OS you running?

Comment: Win8.1 (don't judge, work pc =/ )

Comment: @T.J. Np lol closest I got is a virtualbox of XP that I will check it out on.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I've exhausted all the options I can think of. I have no idea why it's throwing that error. And it doesn't seem like anyone else (at least that I can find) is encountering it.

Comment: Just did fresh x86 Python 2.7.11 install and just install onionpy via pip: pip install onionpy… so far so good.

Comment: From Python command line did the following: from onion_py.manager import Manager then from onion_py.caching import OnionSimpleCache and both work fine

Comment: I suggest you purge the onionpy install completely and reinstall via pip and see if that works.

Comment: It's "working", I'm able to create instances, but it's throwing SNIMissingWarning. But that's probably an issue for another thread. I'm not sure why the package was funking the first time, but reinstalling seemed to address it. Thank you.

Comment: @T.J. Np! Please vote up the answer, I edited it with the complete troubleshooting guide.

Comment: @T.J. First time I actually used windows xp to troubleshoot and answer a question. ;)

Comment: I've made a note to upvote as soon as I've hit 15 rep.